# Which SHA-256 is correct? The Java SHA-256 digest or the Linux commandline tool

Tags: java, security, hash

When I calculate in Java an SHA-256 of a string with the following method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

    byte[] hash = md.digest("password".getBytes());

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(byte b : hash) {
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff));
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

I get :

```
5e884898da2847151d0e56f8dc6292773603dd6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
```

on the commandline I do the following (I need the `-n` to not add a newline) :

```
echo -n "password" | sha256sum
```

and get

```
5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
```

if we compare these more closely I find 2 subtle differences

```
5e884898da2847151d0e56f8dc6292773603dd6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
```

or :

```
5e884898da28   47151d0e56f8dc6292773603d   d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
5e884898da28 0 47151d0e56f8dc6292773603d 0 d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
```

Which of the 2 is correct here?

**Result:** Both are but I was wrong...

fixed it by using :

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(byte b : hash) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'll take a reasonable guess: both are outputting the same digest, but in your Java code that outputs the `byte[]` result as a hex string, you outputting small byte values (less than 16) without a leading 0. So a byte with value "0x0d" is being written as "d" not "0d".

Comment: Yep, just saw your update with code -- this is the problem. `Integer.toHexString()` will not write the leading 0. Might be easiest to just special case values less than 16 and write a '0' in front.

Comment: Silly me! Thanks for the swift response! I just got lucky with my MD5 implementation. Great save...

Answer (score 10):

The culprit is the `toHexString`. It appears to be outputting `6` for the value 6 whereas the `sha256sum` one is outputting `06`. The Java docs for `Integer.toHexString()` state:

> This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in hexadecimal (base 16) with no extra leading 0s.

The other zeros in the string aren't being affected since they're the second half of the bytes (e.g., `30`).

One way to fix it would be to change:

```
for(byte b : hash) {
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff));
}
```

to:

```
for(byte b : hash) {
    if (b < 16) sb.append("0");
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

They're both right - it's your Java code that is at fault, because it is not printing out the leading 0 for a hex value less than 0x10.

Answer (score 4):

You still need "echo -n" to prevent the trailing \n

Answer (score 2):

The one generated by sha256sum seems correct. Your implementation seems to drop those two zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Using @paxdiablo idea had problem with big number as it appear as negative, so

Instead of:

```
for(byte b : hash) {
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff));
}
```

you could do:

```
for(byte b : hash) {
    if (b > 0 && b < 16) {
        sb.append("0");
    }
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff));
}
```

And read [@Sean Owen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021970/which-sha-256-is-correct-the-java-sha-256-digest-or-the-linux-commandline-tool/3021992#3021992) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the right result using this:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

byte[] hash = md.digest("password".getBytes());

BigInteger bI = new BigInteger(1, hash);

System.out.println(bI.toString(16));
```

Comment: No, this code is still wrong. The BigInteger.toString(16) will not containing leading zeros.